# How can i make custom Polymer element hidden?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

For experiments I use the custom element **tute-stopwatch** from https://www.dartlang.org/docs/tutorials/polymer-intro/

When I set the attribute '.hidden = true' for buttons, these buttons hide successfully, but the element `tute-stopwatch` doesn't.

```dart
  void addChild(Event e, var detail, Node target) {
    ..
    stopButton.hidden = true;
    startButton.hidden = true;
    resetButton.hidden = true;

    this.hidden = true; 
}
```

When i use subtemplate in tute_stop_watch.html:

```html
<template if="{{ visible }}" id="innerTemplate">
```

and in tute_stop_watch.dart:

```dart
  void enteredView() {
    super.enteredView();
    startButton = $['startButton']; // $['startButton'] == null
    innerTemplate =$['innerTemplate'] // find correct, but innerTemplate.childNodes == []
```

I try make element with all abilities tute-stopwatch visible on demand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following style to your polymer elements:

```html
<polymer-element name="tute-stopwatch">
  <template>
    <style>
      /* old style for current Dartium */
      @host {
        * {
          display: inline-block;
          position: relative;
          overflow: hidden;
        }

        [hidden], .hidden {
          display: none;
        }
      }

      /* new style for Chromium */
      :host {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      :host([hidden]:host, .hidden:host) {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>

    <button>xxx</button>
    ...

  <template>
  <script type="application/dart" src='toute-stopwatch.dart'></script>
</polymer-element>
```

The you can make the element visible/hidden by setting the `hidden` attribute or add/remove the class `hidden`.

Comment: Thank you ! `this.hidden` is working after this magic. Where can i read more about `:host([hidden]:host, .hidden:host)` and this is working in the Chromium only?

Comment: Dartium is a little behind but the old style will be replaced soon. You can find more about this [A Guide to Styling Elements](http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/styling-elements.html) or [Polymer-Elements](https://github.com/search?q=polymer_ui*&ref=cmdform). There are many more elements not starting with 'polymer_ui' though.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Happy New Year !

Comment: Gunter, what does your selector mean? What is `[hidden]:host` and `.hidden:host` .... this doesn't work with `:hover#myElement` so im curious what your implementation does, can you show a jsfiddle?

Comment: Uh, that's 2 years old, I can't remember I ever knew about this. Probably some experimental selector that was dropped) I guess this was what `:host-context` (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/?redirect_from_locale=de) is now.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the entire template:

```html
<template>
    <template if="{{ visible }}">
     CONTENT
    </template>
</template>
```

Where `visible`is a `@published` boolean.

And then you might have a method in dart like:

```dart
void hide() {
    visible = false;
}
```

Which you could call with an on-click link in the HTML.

Comment: Thank you! It's work. But when i use subtemplate <template if="{{ visible }}">

Comment: You seem to be putting dart code Inside the template? Perhaps you should seperate this into two questions now?

Comment: Sorry. It's my first question here. I add dart code in "tute_stop_watch.dart"

Comment: Thank you for your help. Happy New Year !